# Excel, VBA, convert number to text with numberformat="@" working or not?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

The basic rule to tell text from number is that text is left-aligned and number is right-aligned.

In a blank cell, I set the format to *text*. Then, I entered `25`. This "number" was left-aligned, implying it was text. There was a green triangle on the upper-left corner of the cell with a note saying

> "The number in the cell is formatted as text...".

So far so good.

In the cell right below, I entered `25`. It was right-aligned, implying it was number. I then ran the code `Range.NumberFormat="@"` on it. It became left-aligned. However, there was no green triangle.

When I used `=IF(A1="25",1,0)` to check the first cell, the formula returned `1`. Same test (difference address, of course) on the next cell returned `0`.

It seems to me the code converted `25` to text (judging from the alignment) and at the same time not converted `25` to text (judging from the lack of a green triangle and the `IF` test.)

What's going on?

Comment: Ok, so entering the number and then manually changing the format of the cell to text makes it left align the number but doesn't change the number to a string.  And doing it with VBA is the same.  The number is stored as a string only if the number format is set to text before entering the number.

Comment: This works: `Range("A1") = Str(Range("A1"))` and so does `Range("A1") = "'"&Range("A1")`

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the most efficient method, but it works:

```
Option Explicit
Sub convertText()
    Dim testValue As Variant
    testValue = ActiveCell.Value & ""
    ActiveCell.ClearContents
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@"
    ActiveCell.Value = testValue
End Sub
```